# Using Sharepoint with ArcGIS Server?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, installation, sharepoint

Want to do some testing with [Sharepoint/MapIt](http://resources.esri.com/help//9.3/MapIt/esriparts/v1.1/help/).

- Took an existing machine with ArcGIS Server 10 on Windows Server 2008 on.
- Installed Sharepoint 3.0 SP2 on it with basic install/default options.
- Can now hit Sharepoint with http:///default.aspx
- Can no longer hit manager or REST = 404
- Under wwwroot, the ArcGIS folder is still there

So whats happened and how can I get the two to work side by side?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this, but you'll need to configure distinct host headers on the IIS sites used by ArcGIS Server (probably Default) and SharePoint (probably SharePoint - 80).  The underlying issue is that SharePoint and ArcGIS Server use different directories on disk.

Answer (score 3):

SpConfigUtility.exe

To add components to particular web applications or site collections, use the -url parameter (e.g. "spconfigutility -install -url http://localhost:1234"). Multiple urls may be specified in one command (e.g. "spconfigutility -install -url http://localhost:1234 -url http://localhost:5678"). If the url is that of a web application (or site collection at a web application's root), then the ESRI Parts will be activated on each site collection within the web application. If the url only specifies a site collection, **then the ESRI Parts will be activated only within that site collection**

Since ArcGIS Mapping for SharePoint is built on the Microsoft Silverlight platform, IIS must also be configured so that it includes the following MIME types:

.xaml   application/xaml+xml

.xap    application/x-silverlight-app

.xbap   application/x-ms-xbap

Comment: Thanks mapperz.
Just for info, IIS7 = has these Mime types already ready to go.
Ill leave Q open for few more days to see if i get some more As.
I was hoping I could change something after ive already done the damage.  I do have the option of rolling back if need be.
Id also have preferred to have an option within the install options for ShPt as opposed to relying on a separate utility.
But thanks again - if this is the only workaround, ill take it.

Comment: Your welcome, glad it helps. If there is a better solution would like to know about it too.